# How can I force Selenium tests running on a jenkins slave-node to run in the foreground?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, jenkins, selenium, java-web-start

I have a CentOS server running a Jenkins server that has a connection to slave-node running windows server 2016.   the Jenkins server has a job that is  configured to run a series of Selenium tests on the slave-node.

for the launch method of the slave-node configuration i am using "Launch Agent by connecting it to the master" and I've setup the slave-node create the connection on startup.

the tests can run successfully but when I remote into the windows-slave node via RDP and start the build from the Jenkins server I am unable to see a browser launch and show see the Selenium test interact with the webpage unless I re-lauch the slave-agent within the Remote Desktop connection.

I have tried to running the Jenkins slave-agent as a windows service and also tried starting it with a batch script running at startup but I get the same result.

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://{Jenkins Server URL}/computer/{Jenkins Node}/slave-agent.jnlp
```

is there any way to have the slave-agent run at start-up but also have Desktop interaction when the when I start the Selenium test from a Jenkins build?

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate for DevOps or StackOverflow.  See https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13805/should-we-do-something-about-the-high-number-of-jenkins-questions-with-no-votes

Comment: @jayhendren is it possible for normal users to migrate a post?  I haven't been able to find info on how to do it.    should I just delete this question and re-ask it on one of the other forums you mentioned?